# How to rotate around shifter center precisely in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

If I select `Rotate tool`, I can select center of rotation then and move it. After that I am able to rotate object around that center. But this rotation is imprecise. Suppose I want to rotate for 120 degrees. I can double click on `Rotate tool` and get `Rotate` dialog, where I can enter precise value in degrees. But this way I can't use shifted center of rotation because it jumps back to geometric center at the moment I call `Rotate` dialog.

Is it possible to rotate by precise angle with dialog and have shifted center of rotation.

Answer (score 9):

With the `Rotate` tool active, hold down the `Alt` key (`⌥` on OS X) then click the point you want to rotate the object around. The Rotate dialog box will then pop up and you can enter your precise angle.

Comment: Will my rotation point snap precisely to intersection of guidelines in this situation?

Comment: If you have Smart Guides on, then yes. With that enabled, you should see "intersect" pop up when you hover over the intersection of the guides: http://i.imgur.com/dJpIU.png

Answer (score -1):

If you hit ctrl D after the first rotation copy, you can duplicate the object around the center. Useful for diving a circle into slices.