# Adobe Illustrator - rotate about point

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an object I want to rotate about a specific point.

[image]

[How to rotate around shifter center precisely in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/how-to-rotate-around-shifter-center-precisely-in-illustrator)
I've tried this answer but it doesn't work because when I open the `Transform` -> `Rotate` dialog box and attempt to <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> nothing happens except the rotate dialog box flashes goes it is the focus and not the canvas.

Comment: You are misreading the instructions. Not, transform -> rotate. The **Rotate tool** in the toolbar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to select ROTATE tool then Press ALT + LMB at the position which you want to make Centre of rotation. A rotate pop-up will appear enter the value. That's it.

Here's the Demonstration:

[image]

Comment: how can I accurately snap it to the right center post?

Comment: If you have smart guide enabled it will automatically  snap to the centre point when you move your cursor near the right centre